# EF Code first - context.Add() is not creating new row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have this:

```
var status = new OutTransStatus();
status.StartDate = startDate;
status.TransCount = transactions.Count;
try
{
   context.OutTransStatus.Add(status);
}
catch (Exception)
{
   return 2;
}
```

Now, when i try to add `status`, it goes by, no exception, no nothing, and the row is not applied to the database! What is going on? How can i debug this?

*Edit: Obviously, somewhere above i have using (var context = new Database())*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to save changes:

`context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: It happens to the best of us, my friend.